# Crystal Reports: Need To Add A New Data-Linked Field To Table

Tags: crystal-reports, field, addition

I've recently been revising a report we've been using for years in Crystal Reports 9, a Traveler which displays job information from JobBOSS. I have had a little experience in the past with customizing reports, and this time around I've learned a lot, however, one thing I need to do and can't figure out how for the life of me is this:

How on earth can I add a field to the current table which will link to the correct data? The field I need is an extended description memo. I can add a field by editing the .ttx file using Notepad easily enough, and I can get that added field to show up in the Field Explorer by updating the field definition in the Set Datasource Location window, but when I try to use the field in the actual report through JobBOSS, I get this error message every time:

```
          An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line   490
Char:  2
Error: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B
       (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
Code:  0
URL:   file:///N:/Software/JobBOSS/JobBOSS%
       20Server/Reporting/User-Defined/JBReport.vbs

          Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
```

I'm assuming this is because JobBOSS has no idea what kind of data this field needs, and that makes sense to me, but how do I make the connection with this new field and the correct data in JobBOSS? I've tried renaming the field everything I could think of in case the connection was being made that way, but nothing works. It seems to me like it should be a simple thing and I am just missing something obvious, but I've spent hours searching for the way to do this and have come up empty-handed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Excellent question, the error message has been added, thanks!

Comment: have you tried using stored procedures?

Comment: No I haven't, how would I go about that? Googling for help still isn't proving useful. Would that be the connection I'm looking for?